# If $A$ and $B$ are integral domains and $A \subseteq B$ then $A$ has characteristic $p$ iff $B$ has characteristic $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, integral-domain

Here's my attempt :

The unity of $A$ and the unity of $B$ are both same, so, we'll call it $1$ unambiguously.

$( \Leftarrow )$ Suppose $A$ has characteristic $p$ then $p \cdot 1 = 0$. Since $1$ is also in $B$, it must be that characteristic of $B$, say, $p_{B}$ divides $p$. Also, $p_{B} \ne 1$ thus $p_{B}=p$.

$( \Rightarrow )$ Suppose $B$ has characteristic $p$ then $p \cdot 1 = 0$. Since $1$ is also in $A$, it must be that characteristic of $A$, say, $p_{A}$ divides $p$. Also, $p_{A} \ne 1$ thus $p_{A}=p$.

Is the proof correct? This problem is in Pinter's A book of Abstract Algebra.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг The assumption is that A and B are both integral domains. So they must contain unity, isn't it?

Comment: Does Pinter's definition of a ring include the fact that there exists an element $1$ in every ring? There are other definitions where this condition is not necessary.

Comment: @AshishK That's *probably* what your book states. It's very uncommon to discuss integral domains without identity. So your proof is pretty much what one would expect from the question.

Comment: @AshishK Maybe even more to the point: in a ring with nonzero identity, the characteristic is exactly the additive order of $1$. This links the two things concisely.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг no it doesn't. The definition of an integral domain is that it is a commutative ring with "unity" having no divisors of zeroes.

Comment: @rschwieb ah yes. That's a better way.

Comment: @AshishK Ok , that was my only clarification. Your answer is fine.